# jQuery HTML5 Speech Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make jQuery make the search boxes on my page use x-webkit-speech and submit automatically.

The HTML would obviously be:

```
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" onwebkitspeechchange="this.form.submit();" />
```

I can add the x-webkit-speech attribute with jQuery, but I can't seem to get onwebkitspeechchange to work.

This doesn't work since jQuery doesn't have a onwebkitspeechchange method

```
jQuery("[name=s]").attr("x-webkit-speech", "x-webkit-speech").onwebkitspeechchange("this.form.submit()");
```

But I figured something like this would work:

```
jQuery("[name=s]").attr("x-webkit-speech", "x-webkit-speech").attr("onwebkitspeechchange", "this.form.submit()");
```

But it doesn't. It just doesn't do anything. How can I add `onwebkitspeechchange="this.form.submit();"` using jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind):

```
$(...).bind('webkitspeechchange', function() {
    // submit the form
});
```