# Is there a "onFinishedSpeeking" option for html5 x-webkit-speech?

Tags: forms, html, webkit

I am creating an html5 app that uses x-webkit-speech.

For those not familiar with x-webkit-speech, it is added to regular inputs like this, `<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />`, and then gives the user the ability to use their voice instead of their keyboard.

I was wondering how to submit a form when you are done speaking. Google does it on their homepage, so I know it is possible, I just have no idea how to do it.

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Just to be sure: it is written 'speaking'. So onFinishedSpeaking would be more logical.

Comment: found possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393410/jquery-html5-speech-input

Comment: @F.Calderan That is using Jquery

Comment: but the event is the same, jquery or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this webkit demo](http://www.phpied.com/files/speech-input/speech.html) by stoyan stefanov, the event you're looking for is `onwebkitspeechchange`