# How Create Search Engine Which Search Automatically After Voice Recognition

Tags: css, html, webkit, speech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery HTML5 Speech Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393410/jquery-html5-speech-input)

I want create an search engine for my site which will use Speech Recognition, x-webkit-speech code, but the thing is i want as soon as users speaks query and it recognize it has to search automatically currently users has to press Search button or hit enter button, i am using following code :-

`<form method="get" action="http://www.mysite.com/search/">
 <input type="speech" id="speech" name="i" size="50" x-webkit-speech />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>`

Can you plz tell me what i need to add and where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the JQuery library: http://jquery.com/

Simply add this code to your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add then add this line to your JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#speech').bind('webkitspeechchange',function()
    {
        $(this).parent('form').submit();
    });
});
```